# How to get motion blur without an animation

Tags: photorealism, motion-blur

I have scene where the spider man is falling from a height .I am just making a render and I don't wanna get my hands dirty by adding an animation to the camera and the rig.I guess motion blur won't work unless I have an animation. So I wanted to know how to make a background motion blur to my scene to make it more realistic...I hope it will also  tell the viewers that spiderman has been falling at a high velocity. But now my spiderman looks like he is standing in mid-air.I would love to know if there is any way to do it ?[image]

Comment: i think this tutorial is related to what Susu says: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s6mS7S0haBQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a directional blur node in the compositor for the background, it should work for all other superheroes as well.

[image]

Comment: That would be the perfect option only if my camera was pointing the character from a front view but my camera is placed behind the person.So I wanted a blur that is going in all direction like what a sunbeam node would do...Sorry that I didn't upload the image

Comment: Also how can I separate my foreground and background

Comment: In your case you need to use the zoom settings on the node. For other questions please use a different post. And, yes, next time please add more info, so that others don't have to guess what you want.

Comment: Can you add that to the answer,please?